# Use transition().on("end") in d3 v5 with multiple types of objects

Tags: animation, d3.js, automatic-ref-counting, transition

My goal is to have an animation appear after some arcs have animated on an arc graph.  I first place the nodes, then on a user's click, I highlight the clicked (source) node, and animate the arcs.  What I can't make work is the animation of the target nodes after the arcs have finished animating.  I think what is happening is that the nodes get the new colors, but then get overwritten because on("end") is executed for all nodes and all arcs.  I don't know how to make it run for just the targets of the selected source node.  Here is my code so far.

```
// adapted from https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/arc_highlight.html
// and https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/arc

animateArcsFromNodesForEach = {
  const radius = 8;

  const container = d3.select(DOM.svg(width+margin.left+margin.right, 
                                      height+margin.top+margin.bottom))
  const arcGroup = container
       .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

  // create the nodes
  const nodes = arcGroup.selectAll("nodes")
    .data(graphData.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.name))
      .attr("cy", height-50)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")

  // create the node labels
  arcGroup.selectAll("nodeLabels")
    .data(graphData.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", d => xScale(d.name))
      .attr("y", height-20)
      .attr("fill", "darkgrey")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(d => d.name)

   // This code builds up the SVG path element; see nodesAndArcs for details
   function buildArc(d) {
      let start = xScale(idToNode[d.source].name);
      let end = xScale(idToNode[d.target].name);
      const arcPath = ['M', start, height-50, 'A', (start - end)/2, ',', (start-end)/2, 0,0,",",
                  start < end ? 1: 0, end, height-50].join(' ');
      return arcPath;   
  }

  // create the arcs
  let arcs = arcGroup.selectAll("arcs")
    .data(graphData.links)
    .enter().append("path")
     .style("fill", "none")
     .attr("stroke", "none")
     .attr("d", d => buildArc(d));

  // When the user mouses over a node,
  // add interactive highlighting to see connections between nodes  
   nodes.on('mouseover', function(d) {

      //  highlight only the selected node
     d3.select(this).style("fill", "firebrick");

     // next, style the arcs      
     arcs
       // the arc color and thickness stays as the default unless connected to the selected node d
       // notice how embedding the reference to arcs within nodes.on() allows the code to connect d to arcd
       // this code iterates through all the arcs so we can compare each to the selected node d
       .style('stroke', function (arcd) { 
          return  arcd.source === d.id  ? 'firebrick' : 'none';})
       .style('stroke-width', function (arcd) {
          return arcd.source === d.id ? 4 : 1;})      
       .attr("stroke-dasharray", function(arcd) {
            return  arcd.source === d.id  ? this.getTotalLength() : 0;})
       .attr("stroke-dashoffset", function(arcd) 
             { return  arcd.source === d.id  ? this.getTotalLength() : 0;})
          // reveal the arcs  
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)

 // this is the part that isn't working
      .on("end", function(arcd) {
          nodes
          .transition().style("fill", function(nd) {
            return ((d.id === arcd.source) && (nd.id === arcd.target)) ? 'firebrick' : 'steelblue';
          })
     })
    });



   // remove highlighting when user mouse moves out of node by restoring default colors and thickness
   nodes.on('mouseout', function () {   
     nodes.style("fill", "steelblue");
     arcs.style('stroke', 'none');
     arcs.style('stroke-width', 1);

   });


   return container.node();
 }
```

Comment: I solved my problem.   First, I assigned an attribute ID to each node.  Second, I defined a function, idToTargetNodes that computes the target nodes for a given node ID.   Then I was able to replace the problematic code with the code below instead.  For some reason I needed to use == instead of === for retaining the color on the source node. 

```.on("end", function() {
         nodes
         .style("fill", function(noded) {
           return idToTargetNodes[thisNode.id].includes(noded.id) || thisNode.id == noded.id ? "firebrick" : "steelblue"});
    
     });```

Comment: I realized that I needed to convert thisNode.id to an integer with +thisNode.id in order to match the type of nodeid.id and make === work.

Comment: I found an even better solution!  Use a filter() on the selection and only apply the transformation to those items.  Here is the code:
   ``nodes
          .filter(function(noded) {
            return idToTargetNodes[thisNode.id].includes(noded.id) 
                  || +thisNode.id === +noded.id})
          .style("fill", "firebrick");``